# Are there stock characters?

Tags: modeling

Newb here, just learning Blender.
In tutorials I see artists creating characters from scratch so I wondered are there stock, undefined characters that you can upload to Blender and then modify from there?

I'm also curious what are sources for character sketches if you don't make your own if maybe you don't draw so well? Is that even a thing?

Sorry for the maybe dumb questions. :)
Thanks.
Jazz

Comment: You can search for whatever baseobject you want in google with ".obj" or ".stl" in the search term. You can then import them into blender with "File -> import"

Comment: Oh, wow. Great info. I had not see that mentioned in the vids I've watched.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a list of useful websites for you :

- https://sketchfab.com/feed
- https://www.blendswap.com/
- https://www.poliigon.com/
- https://www.textures.com/library (*they also have 3D models*)
- https://www.blenderkit.com/

The last link I believe would be the most interesting for you. You just need to create an account. Download the zip file of the add on. Go to file > Preferences > Add ons > Install. And then open the zip file. There are many tutorial videos. You don’t need to browse the web to use this add on, once installed.
Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks so much!!!!!